# Azure DevOps - update Agent pool owner

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-hosted-agent

It is possible to update the owner of an self hosted Azure DevOps agent pool via the UI:

I tried via UI -> Organization settings -> agent pools -> details 
I tried via UI -> Project settings -> agent pools -> details

Is it possible via the REST Api?

Answer (score 3):

After the new feature released recently, it does not support change the owner of agent pool with UI. You can only change it with [REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#identityref) now.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}?api-version=5.1
```

For request body, since you just want to change the owner, according to the request body of doc, you just need to specify the value of owner.

Here is the sample of **request body**:

```
{
    "owner": {
        "displayName": "{owner name displayed}",
        "uniqueName": "{owner account: xxx@xx.com}"
    }
}
```

Note: Please do not try to add `isLegacy` into request body, something wrong occurred and the fixed for this issue is being prepared for release. For more details you can refer to this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/631411/failed-to-update-owner-of-an-agent-pool.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [Pools - Update Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to update the pool:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}?api-version=5.1
```

In the request body you can give the `owner`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

What 'kind of' worked for me was

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/_apis/distributedtask/pools/<poolId>?api-version=5.1 HTTP/1.1

{
  "owner" : {
    "displayName": "<name>",
    "uniqueName" : "<name@contoso.com>",
    "descriptor" : "<userDescriptor>" // it didn't work without this property
  }
}
```

the UI shows the updated owner

```
https://dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/_settings/agentpools
```

but the agentPool details show the old owner

```
https://dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/_settings/agentpools?poolId=<poolId>&view=details
```

?